# Calculate the time stream takes to complete in akka stream with and without async

Tags: asynchronous, akka, akka-stream

I want to calculate the time akka stream takes to complete
object Demo extends App {

```
  implicit val system       = ActorSystem("MyDemo")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis


  System.out.println(elapsedTime)
  val flowA = Flow[String].map { element ⇒
    println(s"Flow A : $element ${Thread.currentThread().getName()}" )
    Thread.sleep(1000)
     element
  }

  val flowB = Flow[String].map { element ⇒
    println(s"Flow B : $element ${Thread.currentThread().getName()}" )
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    element
  }

  val flowC = Flow[String].map { element ⇒
    println(s"Flow C : $element ${Thread.currentThread().getName()}" )
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    element
  }

  import system.dispatcher
  val completion = Source(List("Java", "Scala", "C++"))
    .via(flowA)
    .via(flowB)
    .via(flowC)
    .runWith(Sink.foreach(s ⇒ println("Got output " + s)))
  val stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis
  val elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime
  println(elapsedTime)
  completion.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

Output

```
 0
113
Flow A : Java MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow B : Java MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow C : Java MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Got output Java
Flow A : Scala MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow B : Scala MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow C : Scala MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Got output Scala
Flow A : C++ MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow B : C++ MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Flow C : C++ MyDemo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Got output C++
```

**Queries**

1. the elapsed time `113` gets printed before streams completes, not clear with the reason. I want to print the elapsed time after stream completes the processing
2. how can we calculate the time taken to complete stream processing as as I want to compare results of time taken using `.map` versus replacing `.map` with `.async`

Comment: I'm not sure what the question you're asking is...

Comment: i want to calculate the total time by stream to complete but my output prints elapsed time before streams completes @LeviRamsey

Comment: @LeviRamsey edited my question for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Running a stream is asynchronous.  For

```
val completion =
   // omitted for brevity
   .runWith(Sink.foreach(s => println(s"Got output $s")))
```

`completion` is a `Future[Done]` (the materialized value of `Sink.foreach`) that will be completed with `Done` (a singleton) when the stream successfully completes (the future will be failed if the stream fails).  Effectively that line of code is complete and execution moves on once the stream has been materialized and started.

You can get an upper-bound on the time taken by simply moving the code to calculate the elapsed time into an `onComplete` callback on `completion`.

```
completion.onComplete { _ =>  // there's only one possible value here, so we don't need it
  val stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime
  println(elapsedTime)
  system.terminate()
}
```

Note that this callback will execute at some point after the stream completes, but there are no guarantees that it will immediately be executed.  That said, as long as the system and JVM you're running this on aren't under a heavy load, it's good enough.

Two other things are worth noting:

- `currentTimeMillis` really shouldn't be used for reliable benchmarking: it's not even guaranteed to be monotonic (it can go backwards).  `System.nanoTime` is generally more reliable for this purpose.
- It may be more realistic to take the start time right before `val completion = ???`, as otherwise you're also measuring time to construct the "blueprint" of the stream, not just the time to materialize and run the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build a graph to measure the flow time, maybe it can help you.

```scala
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.FlowShape
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, GraphDSL, Source, Unzip, Zip}

object TimedFlow {
  def apply[In, Out](innerFlow: Flow[In, Out, NotUsed], func: (Long, Long) => Any): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = {
    val flowWithLong = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
      implicit builder =>
        import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._
        val unzip = builder.add(Unzip[In, Long]())
        val zip = builder.add(Zip[Out, Long]())

        unzip.out0 ~> innerFlow ~> zip.in0
        unzip.out1 ~> zip.in1
        FlowShape(unzip.in, zip.out)
    })

    Flow[In]
      .map(in => (in, System.currentTimeMillis()))
      .via(flowWithLong)
      .via(Flow[(Out, Long)].map {
        case (out, beginTime) =>
          val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
          func(beginTime, endTime)
          out
      })
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("QuickStart")
    val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 100)

    implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

    val plusOneFlowWithTimePrint = TimedFlow(plusOneFlow(), (beginTime: Long, endTime: Long) => {
      println(s"begin ${beginTime} end ${endTime}")
      println(s"end - begin: ${endTime - beginTime}")
    })
    val done = source.via(plusOneFlowWithTimePrint).runForeach(println)

    done.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
  }

  def plusOneFlow(): Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[Int]
      .map {
        x =>
          Thread.sleep(50)
          x + 1
      }
  }
}
```